# Extracting xml data from string var in android

Tags: android, parsing, sax

Hi I have post some value using `HttpPost` and convert response into string using

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String rrr=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

rrr contain some xml tags

```
<root>
    <mytag>its my tag</mytag>
</root>
```

Now I have to extract string "its my tag"
I have try to do it with SAX Parser but it give out put null.
Plz, help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XPAth](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html). See the [example](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4012).

Answer (score 0):

See next code how to do it using XmlPullParser. You can do the same with SAX, but with some more manual work.

```
try {
XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
parser.setInput(new StringReader(message));
int eventType = parser.getEventType();

while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    String name;
    switch (eventType) {
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG)) {
                yourValue = parser.nextText();
            }
            break;
    .........
}
```